# how do I write a program that analyzes strings, identifies the hashtags, counts them and adds them to a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

notes

1.The result should be a dictionary, where the keys are hashtags and the values are their respective count.

2.assume that only the basic characters that are also available in ASCII can be used in a hashtag (i.e., a-z, A-Z, 0-9).Every other character (e.g., space or '.') ends the current hashtag.

3.Hashtags need to start with a letter (i.e. not number. e.g. #1 is not a valid hashtag) and cannot be empty.

4.assume that the parameter is always a valid list of strings and you do not need to provide any kind of input validation.

5. hashtags are case-sensitive. #MADRID should be counted as a different hashtag than #madrid.

sample input

```
[
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"
]
```

expected output

```
{'weekend': 2, 'madrid': 3, 'fun': 1}
```

stated but I have no idea what to do next

```
def analyze(posts):
#idk
    
posts = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"]
print(analyze(posts))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just a homework dump, without an actual attempt.

Comment: well, an extremely short way would be to do this: `from collections import Counter; print(Counter(x[1:] for x in ' '.join(posts).split() if x.startswith('#')))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
a = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"
]

d = {}

for i in a:
    b = i.split(" ")
    for x in b:
        if "#" in x:
            if x in d:
                d[x] += 1
            else:
                d[x] = 1
print(d)
```